# filter dataframe by condition when the condition is for the columns and not on the values

Tags: python, pandas, filter, floating-point

I have dataframe with float columns that look similar to this:

```
>>>397.55    400.231   404.42  407.12  465.23  478.92  492.3  501.2  505.6  ...
0   0.23      0.122     0.43   0.11     0.345   0.22   0.66   0.34   0.21
1   0.12      0.443     0.76   0.12     0.22    0.24   0.56   0.11   0.04
2   0.45      0.87      0.23   0.99     0.11    0.44   0.78   0.65   0.23
...
```

I want to filter the dataframe s'll have only column that their value is  between 405.2 to 472.7.
I have tried to filter it with condition on the columns but it did not work:

```
df[(df.columns>405.2)]
>>>ValueError: Item wrong length 224 instead of 10783.
```

224 is the number of columns and 10783 is number of rows.

**Is there any way I can filter my dataframe to be between two values when the values are the column name?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), first `:` means get all rows and columns by condition:

```
df.loc[:, (df.columns>405.2)]
```